# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.io

Tags: java

I am a beginner to java, and right now start learning Java IO API. However when I run this simple `BufferedWriter` program, I got this error

> "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try
>   again"

```
package java.io.demo;

public class BufferedWriterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String directory =System.getProperty("user.home");
        String fileName ="sample.txt";
        String absolutePath =directory + File.separator + fileName;
        String text ="This is a text sample";

        try {
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(absolutePath));
            bufferedWriter.write(text);
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am using eclipse photon and java 8
[JRE Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGeAK.jpg)
Any help?

Comment: You probably meant `import java.io.*`, not `package java.io`.

Comment: sorry for that mistake, I created "java.io" package name. I  change the package name to "java.io.demo" but still doesnt resolve the problem.

Comment: No, still not good. Make your package anything that doesn't start with `java.io`. Actually, to be sure, make it start with anything but `java`. make it something like `tunggul.io`.

Comment: It resolve. Thanks a lot man. I never know that package name cannot start with java word

Comment: It's not that they *cannot* start with the `java` word. `javatest` would be valid. But in general it's best that you stick to something that is unique. Like a (reversed) domain name you own (in my case, for example `it.klezlab`) or your preferred nickname (like `tunggul` as I suggested in a previous comment). See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

import java.io.* would work. But as per the error, you are showing shows you have an issue in your jdk installation. Please check your **java version** and **JAVA_HOME** path.

Comment: that import java.io is actually a mistake, I created package with this name and I put this file on it. I changed the package name to java.io.demo and also set JAVA_HOME but still doesnt resolve the issue.

Comment: I notice even you can't use the package name as java.io.*. jdk already has this package so you can't use that. Try to change this.